# Integrating ember-modal-dialog inside a site header Ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js

I'm very new to the Ember framework and I have a question regarding getting a modal setup. I have the site-header as a component. When I click a login button I'd like for a modal to popup. I found the [Ember Modal Dialog](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog) 
plugin and was able to set it up so that there is a modal always shown in application.hbs. However, I'm having trouble understanding a couple of things but first here are my files.

**application.hbs**

```
{{site-header}}
{{outlet}}
{{#if isShowingModal}}
  {{#modal-dialog close="toggleModal"
                  alignment="center"
                  translucentOverlay=true}}
    Oh hai there!
  {{/modal-dialog}}
{{/if}}
{{site-footer}}
```

**site-header.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isShowingModal: false,
  actions: {
    toggleModal: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('isShowingModal');
    }
  }
});
```

So, I have this code for the button in my **site-header.hbs**:

```
<li class="login-button"><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" {{action 'toggleModal'}}>Login</button></li>
```

As I understand it, action is saying to find toggleModal property in the site-header.js and execute the function above which does the property toggling.

1. However, how does application.hbs "see" the value of isShowingModal? Can it even see that value since the modal isn't showing up?
2. When most developers have modals, do they all go inside application.hbs since you want them to appear in the middle of the screen {{outlet}} area? How can you improve the process for including multiple modals?
3. What changes should I make to make the modal show up when the user clicks a button in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok give this a try. In site-header.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    toggleModal() {
      this.sendAction('toggleModal');
    }
  }
});
```

Application.hbs

```
{{site-header toggleModal='toggleModal'}}
{{outlet}}
{{#if isShowingModal}}
  {{#modal-dialog close="toggleModal"
                  alignment="center"
                  translucentOverlay=true}}
    Oh hai there!
  {{/modal-dialog}}
{{/if}}
{{site-footer}}
```

The application controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        toggleModal() {
            this.toggleProperty('isShowingModal')
        }  
    }
})
```

So the action is sent from the site-header component to the site-header component. From there it gets sent to the application controller. In `application.hbs`, `toggleProperty='toggleProperty'` connects the action from the component to the controller's action hash. In the controller action hash, it gets handled by `toggleModal()` and toggles the `isShowingModal` property. When the modal is closed, `ember-modal-dialog` fires an close action that is handled by the `toggleModal()` which again toggles the `isShowingModal` property.

Comment: I don't fully understand. How will the site-component component find the toggleModal property and isShowingModal property if I have the action in the site-header.hbs? The site-header.hbs will only look for properties in it's own .js file right?

Comment: @uioporqwerty edited the answer, hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Application template cannot see the properties of site-header. Only site-header component can see its properties. There are other methods to access them.
2. It is not necessary to include all modals in application. The plugin will most probably handle the positioning. In your case, you can move the modal code to the site-header component also.
3. Put the modal code in your site-header template. (or) You can have isShowingModal variable in application, send an action from site-header to application and toggle its value.